# read data from input card reader into html text box

Tags: php, html

I am working on an application where I need to swipe an access card and read it from an input card reader and store the data in an html text field. This text in this field would then be stored in the database.
Could someone please help me with how to read data from the card reader and capture it in an html text field. 
I am using php. 
Please help!

Comment: I am using Identive SCL011 card reader (905339) and wish to run it on windows xp.

Comment: you should edit your question, rather than add comments about it, also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a PHP issue. The card reader needs to be configured with the computer, and when that occurs the card reader acts as an interface for input (like a keyboard). When a user scans a card the card reader effectively 'types', so your HTML/JS needs to just ensure the input you want populated is selected.

Comment: Thank you for attending my question.

Comment: But i had a doubt. I have installed the drivers needed for the card reader. Do i need another software for the interfacing (i.e. reading the card number from the card reader when i swipe the card.) ?